# css div stick to parent

Tags: css, html

I have the following:

```
<div class="outer">
  <p class="pclass">context...</p>
  <div class="inner">
      <img.../>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

The inner div width is different depending on the image width.

The p width should depend on the image width.

P will contain some dynamic text. The problem is that if p's text is bigger than image widht, it jumps on top of the image.

I've tried to get around this by using css `"text-overflow"`, but that needs a width.

Also not working, setting margin:0 on the img, hoping to make it stick to the surounding div.

Comment: Why does the `<p>` element need to be outside the `<div class="inner">` element? Do you have a screengrab you show of what's happening?

Comment: It is sensitive data and part of a bigger system. I have added a drawing, hope it helps. Thanks

Comment: Do you want the text to sit to the left and the image to sit to the right but both on the same level?

Answer (score 1):

Try the below which simplifies your code a good bit.

```
<div class="outer">
  <p><img src="">context...</p>
</div>

.outer {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.outer img {
    float: right;
    margin: 0 0 20px 20px;
}
```

If you really need to have a DIV around your image you can add one around the image and set it to have the float and margin properties the image has and also set it to display: inline-block e.g.

```
<div class="outer">
  <p><div><img src=""></div>context...</p>
</div>

.outer {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.outer div {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    margin: 0 0 20px 20px;
}
```